# Map shape keys to the 0 - 1 range

Tags: export, unity, shape-keys

I am importing my blender models to Unity and Unity only accepts shape keys in the 0-1 range (no negative values or values greater than 1).  I have a model that has shape keys outside of the 0-1 min/max range.  Is it possible to map the shape key values to this range?

So, for example, the a mesh is at position x at value -1, position y at value 0, and position z at value 1 would be mapped to position x at value 0, y at value 0.5, and z at value 1.

Thanks for any help!